# A quesiton about two similar matrices

Tags: matrices, diagonalization

I was given the following question, but I can't get to prove it, and I would like to have some kind of hint to the answer.
The question is:

> Let A,B be two matrices 2X2 with real numbers, NOT diagonals.
> If (A^t)A = I = (B^t)B and A,B are diagonalizable so A and B are similar.

What I was trying to think about:
I know that (A^t)A = I, so I can get two important pieces of information:

1. A,B are unitary. So the abs of thier eigenvalues is 1.
2. 1 is an eigenvalue for (A^t)A and for (B^t)B.

But I can't connect the pieces of information to give me the reason to believe that A is similar to B.
I can guess that 1 is an eigenvalue for A and B, but I still have one eigenvalue to find for both of them to prove that the sentence is right.

Can anyone please hint me to the answer?
Big thanks in advance.

Comment: Because we assumed that $A,B$ are diagonalizable the eigenvalues can only be $\pm 1$ (I believe that the statement would not be true if they were "only" diagonalizable over $\mathbb C$). Any matrix with two eigenvalues $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 =1$ is similar to $I_2$ - that already implies it would be equal to $I_2$. The same thing applies for $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = -1$ with $-I_2$. So both matrices (as we assumed them to be non-diagonal have to have one eigenvalue $+1$ and one eigenvalue $-1$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: @Lukas Wow, I acutally wrote that A,B are diagonalized, but while trying to solve this question, I forgot this important fact. I knew that the absolute value of the eigenvalues is 1. But since they are diagonalized on real numbers, the eigenvalues HAVE to be +-1. That is the part that I missed. And after your incredible answer, now I finally can understand the answer to this question. Thank you very much, Lukas!